# Wpf Image is not loaded, source issue

Tags: wpf, binding, datatemplate, imagesource

I am trying to bind image source to a string. Ive tried everything that I found by googling but still it does not work.
 My scenario is, I have an Icon folder in my project with some icons in it. I am using Items control like this

```
  <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Options}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource subOptions}" VerticalContentAlignment="Top" >
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>
```

Now my data template looks like this

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="subOptions">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Foreground="White" FontSize="32" Margin="20,10,0,0" Name="TitleTexBlock"/>
            <Border Width="530" Margin="20,10,0,0" Height="200">
                <!--<Image Source="{Binding IconSource, Converter={StaticResource convertStringToImage}}" Width="100" Height="100"/>-->
                <Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}" Width="100" Height="100"/>

                 <!--<TextBlock Text="{Binding ImageSource}" FontSize="30"/>-->
                <Border.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="Border">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=TitleTexBlock,Path=Text}" Value="Defaults">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="DarkRed"/>
                    </Style>
                </Border.Style>
            </Border>
            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Suboptions}" SelectedItem="{Binding ElementName=Options,Path=DataContext.SelectedSuboption}"   ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Inside}" Padding="10,10,10,10" Margin="20,0,0,0" BorderThickness="0">
                <ListBox.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="ListBox">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Title}" Value="Defaults">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="DarkRed"/>
                    </Style>
                </ListBox.Resources>
                <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="LightGreen"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            </ListBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Now the Image that is commented out was using this converter

```
public class ImageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return new BitmapImage(new Uri(value.ToString(), UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)); 
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

The value that was coming to the converter was from here

```
public class Option
{
    public string Title { get; set; }

    private string iconSource = "/Icons/";

    //private string iconSource = "pack://application:,,,MoveA2Options;components/Icons/";
    public string IconSource
    {
        get { return iconSource; }
        set
        {
            iconSource = iconSource + value;
            iconSource += ".png";
        }
    }
```

I know the path created is correct, because I tried with that Texblock commented out in the Xaml and it was showing correct path. 
I also tried this approach

```
public class Option
{
    public string Title { get; set; }

    private string iconSource = "/Icons/";

    //private string iconSource = "pack://application:,,,MoveA2Options;components/Icons/";
    public string IconSource
    {
        get { return iconSource; }
        set
        {
            iconSource = iconSource + value;
            iconSource += ".png";
            imageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri((iconSource), UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
        }
    }

    private ImageSource imageSource;
    public ImageSource ImageSource
    {
        get { return imageSource; }
        set { imageSource = value; }
    }
```

So in this approach that converter is not used, again the textblock shows that the path to the image is correct. But the images either don’t show, or I get some output exceptions. 
Using any image like this

```
<Image Source="pack://application:,,,MoveA2Options;components/Icons/CrateHire.png"></Image>
```

Or this

```
<Image Source="/Icons/CrateHire.png"></Image>
```

Works perfectly fine, any ideas of what else I could try to solve it? Is Image in a DataTemplate treated different than an image in a grid?

Kind Regards

Comment: In DataTemplate posted above you are using `TextBlock` and not `Image` control.

Comment: Yes, that was just to test if the path is correct, but this line <Image Source="/Icons/CrateHire.png"></Image> instead of the textblock does not work

Comment: You don't need to use any `BitmapImage`, `ImageSource`, or `Uri`s to display images in WPF. You can reference images that are in your project simply using your `pack://application` syntax *as long as the **Build Action** of your image files are set to **Resource** in the **Properties** Window*.

Comment: @adminSoftDK - You can bind directly with string value. Default converter will convert your string to ImageSource object, you don't need to worry about it.

Comment: Well, i tried that and the images dont show up,the output window shows these errors, System.Windows.Data Error: 23 :Cannot convert 'pack://application:,,,MoveA2Options;components/Icons/Accounting.png' from type 'String' to type 'System.Windows.Media.ImageSource' for 'en-US' culture with default conversions;                                                  System.Windows.Data Error:6 'TargetDefaultValueConverter' converter failed to convert value'pack://application:,,,MoveA2Options;components/Icons/Accounting.png' (type 'String'); fallback value will be used, if available

Comment: It works in my case though. If it won't have then this `<Image Source="pack://application:,,,MoveA2Options;components/Icons/CrateHire.png"/>` shouldn't have work because here also you specified string which gets converted to ImageSource object. Is BuildAction for Accounting.png set to Resource? More likely converter is not able to locate your resource.

Comment: @RohitVats yes all the images are set to Resource. I thought exactly the same why it does work with the Source ="string", but it does not work with Source={Binding string}". If you have any other ideas, please let me know. It only works if i specify the full path starting from "C://", but this is not what I want.

Comment: private string iconSource = "C:\\Apps\\MoveA\\MoveA\\Options\\MoveA2Options\\Icons\\";
        public string IconSource
        {
            get { return iconSource; }
            set
            {
                iconSource = iconSource + value;
                iconSource += ".png";
            } }                                                                            This is the only way the to make it work in my case, so I can do <Image Source={Binding IconSource} /> and it just works :(

Comment: Like I mentioned conversion from string to ImageSource does work even for Pack URI's string. I tried myself in small sample and it does work. Problem lies somewhere in your code. Try this out in small sample and post the code here if it still persist because with the posted code it's hard to comment what is wrong in code.

Comment: Hi, I had to stop working on that issue, but now I had some time for it. And I created a small example and I actually coppied and pasted the code from the main project. It was working in the sample but it was not in the main project, I did not find out why exactly. But somehow this syntax private string iconSource = "../Icons/imageComesHere"; works. The syntax with the pack, or converters did not work. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution I found in my situation was to modify this line

```
 private string iconSource = "/Icons/";
```

to this

```
  private string iconSource = "../Icons/";
```